# Auto generate employee ids using mysql workbench by creating a function

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

[image]

I have been trying to create a function to generate custom employee ids, even though the logic behind creating the id is correct there is some kind of syntax error.
    I have created a variable and has assigned the right side value of the eid to that variable after casting it to an integer and then has incremented that value by 1 and once again created a string eid

```
CREATE FUNCTION `new_id` ()
RETURNS varchar(50)
BEGIN
set @lastval=(SELECT  MAX(cast(right(eid,4)as int)) from employee);
if @lastval IS NULL SET @lastval=0;
RETURN 'ID' +right('0000' + convert (varchar(50),(@lastval+1)),4);
END
```

I cannot create the function since i get a syntax error in the 4th statement where casting as INT is shown as a syntax error.

Comment: please add error to question. Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a very bad, and unnecessary idea. Why are you doing this?

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde i added a picture

Comment: @Strawberry because i wish to add different string values infront of integer values to create unique ids

Comment: Are you setting delimiters? AND an if needs a THEN and an END IF.

Comment: If this id serves as a component of a PRIMARY KEY/FOREIGN KEY, don't do this. Just have a surrogate PK, and then use application logic to build the 'user-friendly' ids.

Comment: @Strawberry okay will do but can you please tell me why i get such a syntax error

Comment: @P.Salmon i have used but still getting an error

Comment: You cannot convert to varchar only to char see permitted types here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html and + is an arithmetic operator in mysql (are you sure this is a mysql question) use concat instead

Comment: It's just nature's way of telling you that this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you use MySQL, you can try this :

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION `new_id` ()
RETURNS varchar(50)
BEGIN
set @lastval=(SELECT  MAX(cast(right(eid,4)as int)) from employee);
if @lastval IS NULL SET @lastval=0;
RETURN 'ID' +right('0000' + convert ((@lastval+1),varchar(50)),4);
END
```

Comment: sorry but this is the same way i have typed and it gives me a syntax error i have uploaded a picture